# Display a WFS service with OpenLayers 3. Define an add custom projection

Tags: coordinate-system, wfs, openlayers

I am new in OpenLayers 3. I am working with GeoServer 2.6.2 and I would like to create a web mapping with OpenLayers 3.

I am working with a custom projection from El Salvador (Central America). It is not an EPSG projection. I show you in Proj4 format:

```
+proj=lcc +lat_1=14.25 +lat_2=13.3166667 +lat_0=13.783333333333333    
+lon_0=-89 +x_0=500000.00004 +y_0=295809.17715 +k_0=0.999967040229754        
+a=6378206.4 +rf=294.9786982138982 +units=m  +no_defs 
+towgs84=0,105.5,197.2,0,0,0,0
```

OpenLayers library does not recognize this projection. I should define it before calling the WFS Service. I consulted many examples on the web page OpenLayers, but I cannot solve the problem.

Could someone help me?

---

I tried applying the code @Gabor mentioned, but I can not make it work. This is the JavaScript code that I have created:

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:1000', "+proj=lcc +lat_1=14.25 +lat_2=13.3166667 +lat_0=13.783333333333333 +lon_0=-89 +x_0=500000.00004 +y_0=295809.17715 +k_0=0.999967040229754 +a=6378206 +rf=294.9786982138982 +units=m  +no_defs +towgs84=0,105.5,197.2,0,0,0,0"); 


var projSalvador = ol.proj.get('EPSG:1000');
var view = new ol.View({                    
        projection: "EPSG:3857",
        center: [-9888991.9947, 1533959.4220],
        zoom:12,        
        maxZoom:100
});
var vector2Source = new ol.source.ServerVector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
    var url = 'http://localhost/geoserver/workspace/wfs?service=WFS&' +
            'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=workspace:Polygon&' +
            'outputFormat=application/json&format_options=callback:loadFeatures' +
            '&srsname=EPSG:6823&bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
  },
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.createTile(new ol.tilegrid.XYZ({
    maxZoom: 19
  })),
  projection: projSalvador,
});

var loadFeatures = function(response) {
  vector2Source.addFeatures(vector2Source.readFeatures(response));
};

var vector2 = new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: vector2Source,
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 1.0)',
      width: 2
    })
  })
});
```

Browser gives me next problem with this code:

- "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"  (SyntaxError in url wfs code). OpenLayers can not give me any feature, like I can see in json code [{"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":0,"features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"Parcela.9415","geometry"....].

I can not find and fix the problem.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define any projection with a valid Proj4 definition in OpenLayers. OpenLayers 3 can [use](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.4.0/apidoc/ol.proj.html) Proj4JS [version 2.2+](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.3.6/proj4.js). First, you have to define the custom projection with Proj4JS:

```
proj4.defs("NAMEFORMYCUSTOMPROJ", "+proj=lcc +lat_1=14.25 +lat_2=13.3166667 +lat_0=13.783333333333333" + 
"+lon_0=-89 +x_0=500000.00004 +y_0=295809.17715 +k_0=0.999967040229754 +a=6378206" + 
"+rf=294.9786982138982 +units=m  +no_defs +towgs84=0,105.5,197.2,0,0,0,0");
```

With your custom projection defined, you can save the projection object to a variable,

```
var projection = ol.proj.get("NAMEFORMYCUSTOMPROJ");
```

or refer to it with the name string in the constructor.

```
[...]
new ol.source.ServerVector({
    projection: "NAMEFORMYCUSTOMPROJ",
[...]
```